# Display User Profile after Login in php

Tags: php

i am new in php and still learning session in php. i want to display user profile after login. i use session. so, when user login, user can see and  her profile. i have try but still cant. please help me.

this is login process.php

```
<?php 

    session_start();

        require_once("connection.php");

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $nname = $_POST['nname'];
        $bln = $_POST['bln'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];


        $cekuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email'");
        $jumlah = mysql_num_rows($cekuser);
        $hasil = mysql_fetch_array($cekuser);


        if($jumlah == 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('Email belum terdaftar!'); window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
        } else {
            if($password > $hasil['password']) {
            echo "<script>alert('Password Salah!'); window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
            } else {

            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;  
            $_SESSION['nname'] = $nname;    
            $_SESSION['bln'] = $bln;    
            $_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;  

            header('location:index.php');
            }
        }
    ?>
```

this is index.php

```
<?php 

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
        session_start();
    }

    require_once("connection.php");
    include("lib_function.php");
?>

<---header--->

<?php 
     include "connection.php";
     $sql = "SELECT name, email, nname, bln, gender e FROM user WHERE email = '" . $_SESSION['email'] . "'";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     if ($result !== false) {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
         echo "Hello, " . $row['name'] . " <br> " . $row['nname'] ."<br> " . $row['bln'] . " <br> " . $row['gender'] . "(" . $row['email'] . ").";
     } else {
       // an error has occured
       echo mysql_error();
       die;
             }
?>
```

Comment: Where do u set the $_SESSION['email'] ?

Comment: Why do you set a window.location and a header redirect? Password Check looking weired as well. Are you sure you get into the "Else" block?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was something wrong with your `if()` statement. It was telling `if $password is greater than $hasil['password']`. But it have to be equal and you also trying to collect it from an array. So this statement should be:

Process.php:

```
if($password != $jumlah["password"]) {
```

This line says: `if $password is not equal to $jumlah["password"]`

For the second file, you have defined the `$_SESSION` variables, so there is no need to collect the information again with MySQL *(Unless you need the realtime details, than the only thing you need to remove is the `include` line, this is a double line. Also replace `mysql_fetch_array` with `mysql_fetch_assoc`)*.

You may want to check if the sessions exists, so I have write a little example to check that.

**index.php** would look like:

```
<?php 
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
require_once("connection.php");
include("lib_function.php");
?>

<---header--->

<?php
# Check if session 'name' exists
if(isset($_SESSION["name"])) {
    echo "Hello, " . $_SESSION['name'] . " <br> " . $_SESSION['nname'] ."<br> " . $_SESSION['bln'] . " <br> " . $_SESSION['gender'] . "(" . $_SESSION['email'] . ").";\

}else{
    // Do an action to show the user that there is no session.
}
?>
```

I hope this will solve your problem :-)

> Note that `MySQL` is deprecated in the newer versions of PHP, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead. Also your code looks vulnerable to [SQL](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/) and [XSS](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/) injections, it's important to learn about security too while learning in PHP :-)

Answer (score 0):

it should work

Remove the extra blank lines between session_start() function in your `process.php` & `index.php`
 like this

```
<?php 
session_start();

//codes here 

?> 

<?php 
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}


// codes here 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php
$cekuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ".mysql_real_escape_string($email) "AND password = ".mysql_real_escape_string($password));
$jumlah = mysql_num_rows($cekuser);
if($jumlah > 0) {
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;  
    $_SESSION['nname'] = $nname;    
    $_SESSION['bln'] = $bln;    
    $_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;  

    header('location:index.php');
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Password Salah!'); window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
}
?>
```

It Prevents to you from mysql injections

Try Something like this

Hope it will work

Thanks

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).